# web scraping array block html in php

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath, web-scraping

the site web have this strutture html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div calss="header" title="header1">
        <div class="name_header">name_header1</div>
    </div><!-- END HEADER -->
    <div class="body">
        <div class="sub_body" title="sub_body1_header1">
            <div class="information1">Information1</div>
            <div class="information2">Information2</div>
            <div class="information2">Information3</div>
        </div><!-- END SUB_BODY -->
        <div class="sub_body" title="sub_body2_header1">
            <div class="information1">Information1</div>
            <div class="information2">Information2</div>
            <div class="information2">Information3</div>
        </div><!-- END SUB_BODY -->  //THE NUMEBER OF SUB_BODY IS VARIABLE
    </div><!-- END BODY -->

    <div calss="header" title="header2">
        <div class="name_header">name_header2</div>
    </div><!-- END HEADER -->
    <div class="body">
        <div class="sub_body" title="sub_body1_header2">
            <div class="information1">Information1</div>
            <div class="information2">Information2</div>
            <div class="information2">Information3</div>
        </div><!-- END SUB_BODY -->
        <div class="sub_body" title="sub_body2_header2">
            <div class="information1">Information1</div>
            <div class="information2">Information2</div>
            <div class="information2">Information3</div>
        </div><!-- END SUB_BODY -->
        ... MORE SUB_BODY //THE NUMEBER OF SUB_BODY IS VARIABLE
    </div><!-- END BODY -->

    <div calss="header" title="header2">
        <div class="name_header"></div>
    </div><!-- END HEADER -->
    <div class="body">
        <div class="sub_body" title="sub_body1_header2">
            <div class="information1">Information1</div>
            <div class="information2">Information2</div>
            <div class="information2">Information3</div>
        </div><!-- END SUB_BODY -->  //THE NUMEBER OF SUB_BODY IS VARIABLE
    </div><!-- END BODY -->
...MORE ... THE NUMBER OF HEDAER AND RELATED BODY IS VARIABLE
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

Inside the div container there are two block: HEADER and BODY [relative to HEAD]; 
Inside to any BODY there are one o more SUB_BODY and inside to SUB_BODY there are more "information".

I should create an object with data from the HEAD and infusion-related data (first below) BODY. How to do? 
with following code i cycle the HEAD data but do not know how to continue.

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://siteweb.com');
$foo = new DOMDocument();  
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$foo->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
$foo_xpath = new DOMXPath($foot); 
$container = foot_xpath->query('//div[@class="container"]'); 
$num=0;

if($container->length > 0){ 
foreach($container as $row){  

$header = foot_xpath->query('//div[@class="header"]',$row); 
$body = foot_xpath->query('//div[@class="body"]',$row); 

 foreach($header as $row){  
 $name_header= foot_xpath->query('//div[@class="name_header]',$row)->item($num)->nodeAttribute; 
 echo $name_header.'<br/>';

 $num++;

 }//end foreach $header
}//end foreach $container
}//end-if
```